# Checking-out a project to android studio using SVN

Tags: android, svn, android-gradle-plugin

In Android Studio, I want to be able to check out my project with SVN. If I create a new Android Project then Checkout, it does work but some files are already created like string.xml and they are not modified with the checkout, and it's painful to change.

I want to be able to checkout my project "from scratch" without having to tweak anything. I have tried : VCS -> checkout from version Control -> Subversion -> create a new project. This solution seems almost good, it creates a new clean project but I have the following error message :

"Project is not a Gradle-base project". But it is, I do select android-studio/gradle/gradle-2.2.1 as the gradle distribution

Can you help me ? :)